# Socket operation on non-socket, Client server program in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm new to socket programming and I am trying to write a simple socket that connects to another socket on my PC (`nc -l 35353`)

I keep getting a error when trying to bind the socket and I don't know how to debug it.

---

**UPDATE:** The socket call is returning 0 as a file descriptor, although the man page does not say this is illegal, I thought unix/linux reserve fd 0, 1 and 2 for stdin, stdout and stderr by default. I am not sure if this has anything to do with the bind error I am seeing, I just felt this might be appropriate.

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

//typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;

int main()
{
    int sock_fd;
    if( sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket Creation error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;

    memset((char*)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    uint32_t myip = (127<<24)|(0<<16)|(0<<8)|1;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(myip);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(1337);

    int binderror = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr));
    printf("bind error %d\n",binderror);
    if( binderror < 0)
    {
        perror("Bind Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

    memset((char*)&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(35353);
    //unsigned char serverip[] = {127,0,0,1};
    uint32_t serverip = (127<<24)|(0<<16)|(0<<8)|1;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(serverip);

    if( connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ){
        perror("Could not connect\n");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: @m0skit0 In the title, I suspect.

Comment: err... If it's something very obvious, I didn't get it. :(

Comment: use inet_addr("127.0.0.1")

Comment: tried myip = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"). Still get the same error.

Comment: Try with -> `if( (sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){..}...`

Comment: @Vikram This worked. WTH?! why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here -

```
if( sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0)
```

It is old precedence,
`if ( a = b == c )` is like saying `if ( a = ( b == c ))` 
It is calling the function, comparing it with `-1` and assign the boolean result to `sock_fd`

What you suppose to do is -

```
if( (sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
```